# When elements inside the Sun form plasma is there any stratification as densities of different cores are practicaly same?

Tags: density, plasma-physics, sun, elements

When elements inside the Sun form plasma is there any stratification as densities of different cores are practicaly same?Where do electrons accumulate? I pressume it may depend on electron to core density ratio.Let say electrons are liter...should they then move away from the center of Sun although they would in that case feel a proton attraction towards the center of the Sun...

Comment: What do you mean by "different cores"?

Comment: @ProfRob Let say the core of helium has same 'density' as the core of neon...as both are made up of protons and neutrons.Although only helium is present as a fusion product...but neon could be a inpurity formed by an earlier star...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only element that forms inside the Sun (in any quantity) is helium.

The helium that is produced is concentrated at the core. So whilst the surface of the Sun is about 74% H and 25% He (by mass), the core is more like 70% He by mass.

Heavier elements are present in the Sun, at about 1.5% by mass, but are not produced by the Sun. The photosphere is about 1.4% heavy elements by mass and whilst the outer convective zone is thoroughly mixed and homogeneous, there should be a small increase in the metallicity toward the core, caused by gravitational diffusion in the inner radiative zone.

The core itself (the inner 20% radius of the Sun) is also convective, so the helium and small fraction of heavy elements are quite well-mixed in this fully convective region, so there aren't "cores" with different compositions.

The interior of the Sun is an electrically neutral fluid. There is no significant charge separation on large length scales.